# Show a message dialog form outside the main UI thread

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to create a dialog utility unity that could be called in an asynchronous way from different threads and show my dialog message on the active form, and I was sure that TDialogServiceAsync was the perfect way to do it but I can't call the MessageDialog method from outside the Main UI Thread.

Is it possible to achieve what I want without having to actually create a method in my main form that shows the dialog?

I'm developing for Windows right now but a method that could work on multiple plataforms would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Windows, the Win32 `MessageBox()` function can be called in worker threads. But anything based on VCL/FMX dialogs is not thread-safe and should not be called outside of the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, everything that touch the ui must be done in the main ui thread (quite logic). the only think you can do in your background thread

```
TThread.queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    showdialog...
  end);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but TThread.queue is a very useful method that helped me realize the problems with my ideia